# Not recognizing commands in discord with Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I run this, it connects however when running it will not return anything when it comes to commands. I've tried changing this to the context return method from on every message. Previously only one message would appear, now none with this method even though both commands are the same with slight differences. What is my error on this? Sorry this is literally my first attempt at a discord bot.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
botToken = os.getenv("DiscBotToken")

discClient = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@discClient.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{discClient.user} is now connected.")
    print('Servers connected to:')
    for guild in discClient.guilds:
        print(guild.name)

@bot.command(name = "about")
async def aboutMSG(ctx):
    aboutResp = "msg"
    await ctx.send(aboutResp)


@bot.command(name = "test")
async def testMSG(ctx):
    testResp = "msg"
    await ctx.send(testResp)
        

    

discClient.run(botToken)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You heading in the right direction `commands.Bot` have both `event` and `command` no need to use a client just for events.

You should either use `discord.Client` or `commands.Bot` not both in your case it is `commands.Bot`.

Also you are running the client only

```py
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
botToken = os.getenv("DiscBotToken")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{discClient.user} is now connected.")
    print('Servers connected to:')
    for guild in discClient.guilds:
        print(guild.name)

@bot.command(name = "about")
async def aboutMSG(ctx):
    aboutResp = "msg"
    await ctx.send(aboutResp)


@bot.command(name = "test")
async def testMSG(ctx):
    testResp = "msg"
    await ctx.send(testResp)
        

    

bot.run(botToken)
```